# How to extract rotation/transformation information for PDF extracted images (i.e. How does viewers know to rotate 180 )

Tags: pdf, rotation, transformation, rotatetransform, image-extraction

I am using a ScanSnap scanner which generates PDF-1.3 where it will auto-correct the orientation (rotate 0 or 180 degrees) of scanned documents when the PDF is viewed within Adobe Reader. OCR is done by the scanning software and I am assuming the orientation is determined then and encoded into the PDF.

Note that I know I can use Tesseract or other OCR tools to determine if rotation is needed, but I do not want to use it as the scanner software seems to have already determined it and telling PDF viewers if rotation is needed (or not).

When I use image extraction tools (like xpdf pdfimages, python libraries) it does not properly rotate jpeg images 180 degrees (if needed).

> NB: pdfimages extracts the raw image data from the PDF file, without
>   performing any additional transforms. Any rotation, clipping, color
>   inversion, etc. done by the PDF content stream is ignored.

I have scanned a document twice with rotation (0 degrees, and 180 degrees). 
I cannot seem to reverse engineer what is telling Adobe/Foxit to rotate (or not) the image when viewing. I have looked at the PDF-1.3 specification doc, and compared the PDF binary data between the orientation-corrected and not-corrected. I can not determine what is correcting the orientation?

- No /Page/Rotate (defaults to 0) in PDF
- No EXIF orientation in JPEG
- I do not see any transformation matrix (cm operator) in PDF

In both cases the PDF binary looks like the following (stopped at the JPEG streamed data)

**UPDATED:** links to PDF files [rotated-180](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03294969585737255560) [rotated-0](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00344136391322927294)

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Metadata 20 0 R/Pages 2 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</MediaBox[0.0 0.0 606.6 794.88]/Count 1/Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Parent 2 0 R/Contents 18 0 R/PieceInfo<</PSL<</Private<</V(3.2.9)>>/LastModified(D:20190201125524-00'00')>>>>/MediaBox[0.0 0.0 606.6 794.88]/Resources<</XObject<</Im0 5 0 R>>/Font<</C0_0 11 0 R/T1_0 16 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageC]>>/Type/Page/LastModified(D:20190201085524-04'00')>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Subtype/Image/Length 433576/Filter/DCTDecode/Name/X/BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Width 1685/Height 2208/Type/XObject>>stream
```

**Does anyone know how PDF viewers know to rotate an image 180 (or not). Is it meta-data within the PDF or JPEG image which can be extracted?** Does Adobe and other viewers do something dynamically on opening a document to determine if orientation correction is needed?

I'm no expert with PDF specification. But I was hoping someone may have already found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Please post a link to a rotated PDF file so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Indeed, the data you posted do not make a pdf viewer rotate anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I updated the Question to include links to the "rotated-180" PDF.  Also added in "rotated-0" PDF as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image **Im0** in the resources of the page in "internetfile-180.pdf" is not rotated:

[image: internetfile-180.pdf image]

But the image **Im0** in the resources of the page in "internetfile.pdf" is rotated:

[image]

In the viewer both look upright, so in "internetfile.pdf" a technique must be used that rotates the image.

There are two major techniques for this:

- Setting the **Rotate** property of the page accordingly, i.e. here to 180.
- Applying a rotation transformation to the current transformation matrix in the content stream of the page.

Let's look at the page dictionary first, a bit pretty-printed:

```
4 0 obj
<<
  /Parent 2 0 R
  /Contents 13 0 R
  /PieceInfo
  <<
    /PSL
    <<
      /Private <</V (3.2.9)>>
      /LastModified (D:20190204142537-00'00')
    >>
  >>
  /MediaBox [0.0 0.0 608.64 792.24]
  /Resources
  <<
    /XObject <</Im0 5 0 R>>
    /Font <</T1_0 11 0 R>>
    /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageC]
  >>
  /Type /Page
  /LastModified (D:20190204102537-04'00')
>>
```

As we see, there is no **Rotate** entry present. Thus, we'll have to look at the page content stream. According to the page dictionary it's in object 13, generation 0.

That object is a stream object with deflated stream data:

```
13 0 obj
<<
  /Length 4014
  /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
H‰”WÛŽÛF}Ÿ¯Ð[lÀÓÓ÷Ë¾e½
[...]
ÿüòÛÿ ´ß
endstream
endobj
```

After inflating the stream data, they start like this:

```
q
-608.3999939 0 0 -792.9600067 608.3999939 792.9600067 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
[...]
```

And this is indeed an application of the second technique, the **cm** instruction applies the rotation and the **Do** instruction paints the image with the rotation active!

In detail, the **cm** instruction applies the affine transformation represented by the matrix

```
-608.3999939    0            0
   0         -792.9600067    0
 608.3999939  792.9600067    1
```

In other words:

```
x' = -608.3999939 * x + 608.3999939
y' = -792.9600067 * y + 792.9600067
```

This transformation actually is a combination of a rotation by 180°, a horizontal scaling by 608.3999939 and a vertical scaling by 792.9600067, and a translation by 608.3999939 horizontally and 792.9600067 vertically.

The **Do** instruction now paints the image. Here one needs to know that this instruction first scales the image to fit into the unit 1×1 square at the origin and then applies the current transformation matrix.

Thus, the image is drawn rotated by 180°, effectively filling the whole 608.64×792.24 **MediaBox** of the page.

Answer (score 0):

**mkl** answered the question correctly doing all the hard work decoding the PDF for me.

I thought I would add in my python (PyPDF2) code to search for the found rotation condition in case it helps someone else.

```py
input1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filepath, "rb"))
totalPages = input1.getNumPages()
for pgNum in range(0,totalPages):
    page0 = input1.getPage(pgNum)

    # Lets look to see if the page contains a transformation matrix to rotate it 180 degress 
    # (ScanScap iX500 encoded the PDF with a cm transformation matrix to rotate 180 degrees in PDF viewers
    # @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483013/how-to-extract-rotation-transformation-information-for-pdf-extracted-images-i-e
    # @see 'PDF 1.3 Reference Manual March 11, 1999' Section 3.10 Transformation matrices which is applied to the scanned image
    #                                          [[a b 0]
    #                                           [c d 0]
    #                                           [e f 1]] 
    isPageRotated180 = False
    pgContent = page0['/Contents'].getData().decode('utf-8')
    FLOAT_REG = '([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)'
    m = re.search( '{} {} {} {} {} {} cm'.format(FLOAT_REG,FLOAT_REG,FLOAT_REG,FLOAT_REG,FLOAT_REG,FLOAT_REG), pgContent )
    if m:
        (a,b,c,d,e,f) = list(map(float,m.groups()))
        isPageRotated180 = (a == -e and d == -f)
```